# How to structure node library with multiple entry points?

Tags: node.js

I've got [a library](https://bitbucket.org/cowwoc/requirements.js) that has multiple entry points:

- Requirements
- DefaultRequirements
- GlobalConfiguration

The first is meant to be instantiated multiple times. The latter two are singletons.

This library targets both node and web browsers so placed files in the following folders:

```
/node_modules/@cowwoc/requirements    
  /node    
  /browser
```

Is it possible to have users `import "@cowwoc/requirements/DefaultRequirements"` without having to specify that the actual file is under `node` or `browser`?